# How many km per day in on the road trip to patagonia?

Tags: planning, argentina, chile, adventure

I am planning an on the road trip renting a car from Cordoba, Argentina (where I live) to Ushuaia. Backing home by plane. I am not used to long distance trip by car (I am Italian). The whaol trip would aprox 4k km. How many km per day would be a good trade off between time spent in a car and enjoying beautiful place? Would 400 km per day a good balance?

Comment: it really depends on what kind of roads are on your itinerary and how you like long distance driving. 

Maybe you'll relate with this example but it's clearly not an answer: going from the extreme north of lombardy to the south of Tuscany it has always taken me 6 hours and it's 600 km, mostly on motorways but with traffic sometimes. And it's tiring enough, I would not do that every day. 

It also depends on whether the stops you make every 400 km will be in the middle of nowhere or you can actually enjoy the place. 

I'd say, leave yourself enough leeway to slow down if you get tired.